# Get number of inserted rows by just plain sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

is there a way to get the number of inserted rows inside of the same transaction?
I see that PL/SQL command:

```
SQL%ROWCOUNT
```

does the job, however I don't want to create a procedure just for that!
I tried to simply call

```
insert into T ...
select SQL%ROWCOUNT;
```

but it gives me "invalid character".
If I remember well mysql actually had a way to obtain this information, does oracle really not provide any means for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to create a procedure just for that

No need to create any **procedure**, you could simply use an **anonymous PL/SQL block**.

For example,

```
SQL> SET serveroutput ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2  var_cnt NUMBER;
  3  BEGIN
  4  var_cnt :=0;
  5  FOR i IN(SELECT empno FROM emp)
  6  LOOP
  7  INSERT INTO emp(empno) VALUES(i.empno);
  8  var_cnt := var_cnt + SQL%ROWCOUNT;
  9  END loop;
 10  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(var_cnt)||' rows inserted');
 11  END;
 12  /
14 rows inserted

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

**Update** If you cannot use **PL/SQL**, and just plain **SQL**, then you cannot use `SQL%ROWCOUNT`.

The only option that comes to my mind is to have a **timestamp column** in your table, and query the **count** based on the timestamp to know the number of rows inserted.

Comment: thumbs up, but my problem is that I will be calling those sql statements inside of an ORM and so I cannot make anything like that :/

Comment: Not the best but I guess it's the only way :(

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(TO_CHAR(SQL%ROWCOUNT)||' rows inserted');
```

Comment: You have using oracle or sql server?

Comment: I think @Phate is meaning that `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` is not an SQL command and it cannot run unless it is in a PL/SQL block.